# Rename properties in json response

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Hello I am receiving response from webservice like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1657529234,
    "source": "EUR",
    "quotes": {
        "EURUSD": 1.018589,
        "EURNOK": 10.254409,
        "EURPLN": 4.774992
    }
}
```

i want to cut EUR from name just  to have it like **"USD":1.018589** etc
So i created code:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
---
{
    success: payload.success,
    timestamp: payload.timestamp,
    source: payload.source,
    rates: payload.quotes mapObject ((val, key) ->{
        (substring(key,3,6)):val
    })
}
```

Response is as expected:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "timestamp": 1657529234,
  "source": "EUR",
  "rates": {
    "USD": 1.018589,
    "NOK": 10.254409,
    "PLN": 4.774992
  }
}
```

but AnyPoint Studio returns 1 issue:

```
Expecting Type: `{ K?: V }`, but got: `Array<{|EURUSD: Numb...r, EURPLN: Number|}>`.
    |-- From: `{ K?: V }`
    |---- From: mapObject(object: `{ K?: V }`, mapper: (value: `V`, key: `K`, index: `Number`) -> `Object`) -> `Object`
```

Can you explain me what is wrong with my code even though when i run this i do not receive any errors?

If this help i only set metadata for Transform message as in this image:
[image]

Comment: Have you defined any metadata somewhere for the response?

Comment: According to the answers it seems that the input is really an array. Please provide the right input in your question. Otherwise it is not reasonable to expect a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payload mentioned seems to be an array of objects defined as seen from screenshots. Are you trying like below:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
---
payload map 
{
    success: $.success,
    timestamp: $.timestamp,
    source: $.source,
    rates: $.quotes mapObject ((val, key) ->{
        (substring(key,3,6)):val

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi The problem is that according to your UI your payload is an Array of Object so payload.quotes is going to return an Array of quotes. This is because dot selection over array applies the value selection in all the object elements of the array